# Can't set attribute for Pytorch LightningModule

Tags: python, pytorch, pytorch-lightning

I am trying to import initiate a LightningModule class module, but for some reasons i unable to set `hparams`. However if i change the name to `hparams2` it suddenly seems to work. I have no idea how and any feedback would be apricated,.

```
import pytorch_lightning as pl
class ImagenetTransferLearningWorks(pl.LightningModule):
    def __init__(self, num_classes = 10):
        super().__init__()
        self.hparams2 =SimpleNamespace(
           num_classes = num_classes
          )
        
        #self._create_network()
        

class ImagenetTransferLearning(pl.LightningModule):
    def __init__(self, num_classes = 10):
        super().__init__()
        self.hparams =SimpleNamespace(
           num_classes = num_classes
          )
        
        
ImagenetTransferLearningWorks()
ImagenetTransferLearning()
```

results in the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-3180059140582422> in <module>
     20 
     21 ImagenetTransferLearningWorks()
---> 22 ImagenetTransferLearning()

<command-3180059140582422> in __init__(self, num_classes)
     14     def __init__(self, num_classes = 10):
     15         super().__init__()
---> 16         self.hparams =SimpleNamespace(
     17            num_classes = num_classes
     18           )

/databricks/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in __setattr__(self, name, value)
   1176                     buffers[name] = value
   1177                 else:
-> 1178                     object.__setattr__(self, name, value)
   1179 
   1180     def __delattr__(self, name):

AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

I don't understand what goes wrong here, could someone please explain to me why this happens?

Thank you in advance,